# Is libusb the preferred method on Mac OS X to access USB device?

Tags: cocoa, macos, usb, iokit, usbserial

Is libusb the preferred method to talk to a device over USB (using AT commands) on OS X these days?

Is there any high level equivalent in cocoa?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On OS X, drivers are written using the IOKit and a subset of C++. More specifically, for USB devices, you probably want to start with Apple's [USB Device Interface Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBIntro/USBIntro.html) and browse the USB parts of Hardware and Drivers section of the Mac OS X Core Library documentation set in XCode. (**Edit:** The latter resource is also [available online](http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/HardwareDrivers/idxUSB-date.html).)

Answer (score 1):

I have written driver with libusb that work on both Windows XP, Windows 7, Linux and Mac OS X, so I would say that libusb is a good choice if cross-plattform compatibility is important to you.